# How to shift part of image I put the circle crop on?

Tags: html, css

```
.rounded-profile-img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The above does what I want, but it's not perfectly centered on the person's face. I tried adding

```
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
```

but this didn't have the desired affect as it just moves the whole element.

How can I center the the circle on the proper part of the picture?

Comment: @Paulie_D But I do know where the center of the face is. I'm not asking for help to detect where it is.

Comment: Each picture will be different and you'll need to measure to find the % from the top and % from the left of the center of the face and use that to position the circle.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes exactly... the part about "use that to position the circle" is what my question is asking about. How do I take the measurements and apply them so that it's cropped in the correct place?

Comment: Basically you can't do this with `border-radius` unless the center of the image is also the center of the face. I suggest you look into clip-path's instead.

Comment: Border radius applies to the **whole image** not part of it.

Comment: @Paulie_D okay thanks

Comment: @Paulie_D So maybe this is a dumb question, but is it not possible to apply some transformation that would make the face the center first, and then apply the border-radius?

Comment: @Paulie_D I see an example of how to use clip-path here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path`. However, I could still use some assistance in figuring out how I would take that first example and move the circle around to another place on the image.

Comment: This [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape goes into more detail about radius and so on and gives examples of circle positioning.

Comment: Can you include some example html?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to work with a single `<img>` tag (and avoid additional html) using [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) (these can control how the pixel content of an image is laid out within the `<img>` tag's bounding box). For example this image:

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.OKcL1zoltNwgLG5FCD5oEgHaLJ?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" width="113" height="170" />
```

can be centered simply by adding the appropriate `object-position`:

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 -6px; /* this is the only change */
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.OKcL1zoltNwgLG5FCD5oEgHaLJ?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" width="113" height="170" />
```